# Pact: Error when trying to setup mock provider

Tags: pact, pytest-mock

I'm trying to write my first Pact-python test using **pytest**, Could someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
import unittest

import requests

import json

import pytest

import atexit

from pact import Consumer, Provider

pact = Consumer('Consumer').has_pact_with(Provider('Provider'), host_name='mockservice', port=8080)
pact.start_service()
atexit.register(pact.stop_service)

class InterviewDetails(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_candidate_report_api(self):
        candidate_report_payload = {}
        resp = requests.post("http://localhost:1234/users/",data=json.dumps(candidate_report_payload))
        response = json.loads(resp.text)
        return response

    @pytest.mark.health1
    def test_candidate_report(self):
        expected = {}
        (pact.given('Comment')
         .upon_receiving('comment')
         .with_request(method='POST', path="http://localhost:1234/users/", headers={})
         .will_respond_with(200, body=expected))
        with pact:
            pact.setup()
            result = self.test_candidate_report_api()
            self.assertEqual(result, expected)
            pact.verify()
```

The error from **stacktrace**:

> AttributeError: module 'pact' has no attribute 'Like'

Comment: Perhaps if you could please create a github repo with your example code, that would be really helpful in diagnosing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm you're using `pact-python` from https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-python/ (and not pactman, a project that is not maintained by the Pact Foundation)?

It might be related to the way you have setup your test?

Here is an example project you can use for reference: https://github.com/pactflow/example-consumer-python/

Relevant test code:

```py
"""pact test for product service client"""

import json
import logging
import os
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

import pytest
from pact import Consumer, Like, Provider, Term, Format

from src.consumer import ProductConsumer

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
print(Format().__dict__)

PACT_MOCK_HOST = 'localhost'
PACT_MOCK_PORT = 1234
PACT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


@pytest.fixture
def consumer():
    return ProductConsumer(
        'http://{host}:{port}'
        .format(host=PACT_MOCK_HOST, port=PACT_MOCK_PORT)
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def pact(request):
    pact = Consumer('pactflow-example-consumer-python').has_pact_with(
        Provider('pactflow-example-provider-python'), host_name=PACT_MOCK_HOST, port=PACT_MOCK_PORT,
        pact_dir="./pacts", log_dir="./logs")
    try:
        print('start service')
        pact.start_service()
        yield pact
    finally:
        print('stop service')
        pact.stop_service()

def test_get_product(pact, consumer):
    expected = {
        'id': "27",
        'name': 'Margharita',
        'type': 'Pizza'
    }

    (pact
     .given('a product with ID 10 exists')
     .upon_receiving('a request to get a product')
     .with_request('GET', '/product/10')
     .will_respond_with(200, body=Like(expected)))

    with pact:
        user = consumer.get_product('10')
        assert user.name == 'Margharita'
```